Issue with JSON Parsing in Node.js Stream from Athena Query Execution
I'm encountering an issue with a Node.js stream that reads data from an Athena query execution. The stream throws an error indicating that it cannot parse JSON. However, when I manually execute the query on the Athena console, download the results, and process the same logic on the downloaded CSV file, no error occurs. This leads me to believe the problem lies with the stream itself, particularly with the last chunk of data.
Here is the relevant code:
async function runQueryForAllMatches(query, processMatchesCallback) {
  const queryStream = someClient.execute(query).toStream();

  const isValidJSON = (string) => {
    try {
      JSON.parse(string);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  const executeQuery = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    queryStream.on('data', async (data) => {
      queryStream.pause();
      try {
        const matchesData = data['matches_data'];

        if (!isValidJSON(matchesData)) {
          console.error(`Invalid JSON: ${matchesData}`);
        } else {
          const parsedData = convertData(data['subscriber_id'],data['subscriber_matches_data']);
          await processMatchesCallback(parsedData);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Stream data error: ${e.message || e.toString()}`);
      }
      queryStream.resume();
    });

    queryStream.on('end', () => {
      resolve();
    });

    queryStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
  });

  await executeQuery;
}

Problem Description
When processing the stream, the code intermittently throws an error that it cannot parse JSON, specifically for the last chunk of data. The error does not occur when the same data is processed from a manually downloaded CSV file. This suggests that the issue might be related to how the stream handles the last chunk of data.
Additional information
When I was debugging the chunk of data that was the reason of error was incomplete and by that I mean the JSON object cut in some part.
Question
What might be causing the JSON parsing error in the Node.js stream, and how can I resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
